# Increasing value in a water method labyrinth problem

Tags: java

I have been working on a school project recently - generate a maze from 1 and 0, create random start and finishing points inside a maze and track the shortest route between them. 1 is path, 0 is wall.

I chose to emulate flowing water - I begin from the start coordinates and once there is value 1 (up, down, left or right of it) I increase the value of the counter making a path the end. The goal is that the shortest route can be traced form the end value by going backward on the counter.

The issue I have is with increasing the counter to fill the maze.
Hopefully the code will tell more.

```
public class Labyrinth {

    static int jk, ik, is, js; //start and end coordinates
    static int tmp[][]= new int[10][10];;
    static Integer stala=2; //The counter
    //static Integer licz;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Stworzenie tablicy 0 i 1
        int tab[][]= new int[10][10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                tab[i][j]= (int) (Math.random() + 0.5);
            }
        }

        //Creating the starting point (99)
        is= (int)((Math.random())*10);
        js= (int)((Math.random())*10);
        tab[is][js]=99;

        //Creating the ending point (66)
        int esc=0;
        while (esc!=1) {
            ik= (int)((Math.random())*10);
            jk= (int)((Math.random())*10);

            if(ik==is || jk==js)
                continue;
            else 
                esc=1;
        }
        tab[ik][jk]=66;

        //creating a tmp table to display increased values
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                tmp[i][j]= tab[i][j];
            }
        }

        //executing a method of a flowing water
        przypis(is,js);


        //Displaying the maze and the tmp table maze
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(i>0)
                System.out.println();
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", tab[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("S: "+"("+is+","+js+")");
        System.out.println("K: "+"("+ik+","+jk+")");

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(i>0)
                System.out.println();
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", tmp[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("S: "+"("+is+","+js+")");
        System.out.println("K: "+"("+ik+","+jk+")");

    }

    static void przypis(int a, int b) {
        //a,b
        try {

            if(a!=9) {      
                if((int)tmp[a+1][b]==1) {
                    tmp[a+1][b]=(int)stala;
                    przypis(a+1,b);
                }
            }

            if(b!=9) {
                if((int)tmp[a][b+1]==1) {
                    tmp[a][b+1]=(int)stala;
                    przypis(a,b+1);
                }
            }

            if(a!=0) {
                if((int)tmp[a-1][b]==1) {
                    tmp[a-1][b]=(int)stala;
                    przypis(a-1,b);                     
                }
            }

            if(b!=0) {
                if((int)tmp[a][b-1]==1) {
                    tmp[a][b-1]=(int)stala;
                    przypis(a,b-1);
                }
            }
            stala++;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to make the counters to work - thats my main issue.
The goal is to make it look sth like that:

[image]

@property of s16574

Comment: *"emulate flowing water"* That is [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing such thing is by creating a recursive function that takes the current position in the maze and calls itself recursively to the four positions around current position:

**Pseudocode for such function:**

```
populatesMaze(currentX, currentY, currentCounter, mazeFinishX, mazeFinishY, mazeMatrix):

    // Preventing a corner case in which our current position is outside of the maze...
    if (currentX < mazeMaxtrix.lines and currentY < mazeMatrix.columns and currentX >= 0 and currentY >= 0):
        // Preventing our cursor from walking over walls...
        if (mazeMatrix[currentX][currentY] != 0)
            mazeMatrix[currentPositionX][currentPositionY] = currentCounter
        else:
            return

    // Until our position is not the final one, we keep going...
    if (currentX != mazeFinishX and currentY != mazeFinishY ):            

        populatesMaze(currentpositionX + 1, currentY, currentCounter + 1, mazeFinishX, mazeFinishY, mazeMatrix)

        populatesMaze(currentpositionX, currentY + 1, currentCounter + 1, mazeFinishX, mazeFinishY, mazeMatrix)

        populatesMaze(currentpositionX - 1, currentY, currentCounter + 1, mazeFinishX, mazeFinishY, mazeMatrix)

        populatesMaze(currentpositionX, currentY - 1, currentCounter + 1, mazeFinishX, mazeFinishY, mazeMatrix)
```

Hope it helps you with your assingment!